# Find the area bounded by the graphs $y^2=4+x$ and $y^2 + x = 2$

Tags: calculus

My attempt: $\int 2-y^2 + y^2-4 dy $

I changed the sign of $y^2-x=2$ as I think that the distances must be converted to absolute value. e.g. let $y = 0$, then x must be a positive?

Comment: What limits of integration do you think you need here?

Answer (score 1):

You have the two curves
$$\begin{align}
x &= y^2 - 4 \\
x &= 2-y^2.
\end{align}
$$
The one on top is $x = 2-y^2$ so you have to integrate $2-y^2 - (y^2 - 4)$. Remember to put appropriate parenthesis around the second curve.

Now you also need limits on your integral. You are trying to find a number (the area) and not an antiderivative. So you need a definite integral. You can find the bounds by figuring out where the curves intersect. You do this by solving
$$
y^2 - 4 = 2 - y^2.
$$ 
When you solve this quadratic equation you will get two numbers. The smaller of the two is the lower bound on your integral and the larger is the upper bound.

Also, try to sketch the graphs of the two curves.

Answer (score 0):

Since the curve $x=2-y^2$ is on the right and the curve $x=y^2-4$ is on the left,

and these parabolas intersect where $y^2-4=2-y^2$, $\;\;$so $2y^2=6\implies y^2=3\implies y=\pm\sqrt{3}$,

$A=\displaystyle\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}\big((2-y^2)-(y^2-4)\big) dy=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\big(6-2y^2\big) \;dy=4\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\big(3-y^2\big) \;dy$
using symmetry.